# Capybara::ElementNotFound issue with remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a form which I am submitting using remote=>true

```
<%= form_tag fetch_data_path, :remote => true do %> 
    Date: <%= text_field_tag :date %>
    Amount:<%= text_field_tag :amount %>
    From:<%= text_field_tag :from %>
    To:<%= text_field_tag :to %>

 <%= submit_tag "Convert"%> &nbsp;

<% end %>


<span style="font-weight: bold;">Converted Amount:</span> 
<div id="converted_amount"></div>
```

On submitting the form, the converted value is displayed in the div with id

> #converted_amount

Here is my rspec:

```
RSpec.feature "User performs exchange", :type => :feature do
  scenario "with valid input" do
    visit exchanges_path
    fill_in 'date', :with => "2017-08-24"
    fill_in 'amount', :with => "100"
    fill_in 'from', :with => "pound"
    fill_in 'to', :with => "dollar"
    click_button('Convert')

    expect(page).to have_text("Converted Amount:")
  end
end
```

The issue is that when I run it, I get

> Capybara::ElementNotFound:        Unable to find xpath "/html" and yet when I comment out click_button, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara? Additionally, what version of Capybara and the specific driver are you using?

Comment: capybara (2.15), capybara-webkit (1.14.0)

Comment: I should mention that I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I added the following gems to my Gemfile

```
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

and then added `:js => true` to my spec file. It became:

```
RSpec.feature "User performs exchange", :type => :feature do
  scenario "with valid input", :js => true do
    visit exchanges_path
    fill_in 'date', :with => "2017-08-24"
    fill_in 'amount', :with => "100"
    fill_in 'from', :with => "pound"
    fill_in 'to', :with => "dollar"
    click_button('Convert')

    expect(page).to have_text("Converted Amount:")
  end
end
```

Comment: You also had to have specified `Capybara.javascript_driver = <something>` , and you don't need both `capybara-webkit` and `selenium-webdriver` - you use one or the other.  You also don't need to specify `:type => :feature` when you use `RSpec.feature`

Comment: Additionally, since you said it passed previously when you removed the `click_button`, that would imply the text "Converted Amount:" is already on the page before clicking the button, so it's not a good thing to be expecting to indicate the `click_button` has completed.

Comment: Thanks for all this information. I wasn't aware of all these. I am using execjs and I didn't specify 'Capybara.javascript_driver'.

Comment: `execjs` has nothing to do with Capybara.  If you haven't specified a specific javascript_driver then it will default to `:selenium` which will use `selenium-webdriver` with Firefox for JS testing.  You don't need the `capybara-webkit` gem for that.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you very much.